# Index in sqlite causing me trouble and slow requesting

Tags: performance, sqlite, indexing

Hello I have a table with +800'000 rows in sqlite.

I've indexes on each fields I'm used to search. But my request rate is SLOW:

```
SELECT "links".* FROM "links" 
WHERE "links"."from_id_admin" = "XXXX" 
AND "links"."from_type" = "Section"   
ORDER BY category_rank DESC, rank DESC
```

it took me 800ms. (return only one row, all the time is wasted on index lookup)

I investigated further with "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN" and here is the result:

```
"SEARCH TABLE links USING INDEX index_links_on_from_type (from_type=?)"
"USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY"
```

Weirdly, Sqlite is using only the from_type index. The problem is there's not so much discrimination on this index (there's 4 or 5 differents values).

If I remove the clause WHERE enough, my request is fast as expected (2ms):

```
SELECT "links".* 
FROM "links" 
WHERE "links"."from_id_admin" = "XXXXX" 
ORDER BY category_rank DESC, rank DESC
```

Yeah. Less discrimination means 400x speed improvement. So my question is:

- Is that normal behavior?
- How can I avoid it?
- Can I force the search pattern to lookup to the proper index?

Thanks for your answers ;-)

Yacine.

Comment: Have you verified that the index not being used is present and properly populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found it:

My SQLite database was populated with large amount of data (2Gb) then I never called "ANALYZE" to check the datas and optimize the index use.

So after big change in your database, always use:

```
ANALYZE
```

Took one second and half and then everything works properly!

Good to know I guess ;-)